# jquery .load() , loads a white page

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

i have a problem with jquery.
when i use the .load() api it doesn't work.
i use this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
                $("#loading").show();
            }).ajaxStop(function(){
                        $("#loading").hide();
                    }).ajaxError(function(){
                        alert("Error on load page!");
                    });
            $("ul li a").on("click", function(){
                var twLink = $(this).attr( 'href' );
                //i used the event.preventDefault(); too, but it does not work
                $("#Container").load( twLink + "#ContainerChild" );
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

it goes to a white blank page that there are the ads in the page!
but when i use this code in w3 schools try it editor it works perfectly!

i have a demo from the problem : http://www.nowsud.rzb.ir 
and go then click on the "موضوعات"! (see the pic of this location: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLPDl.jpg) lists too see the problem.

well i want to make my blog ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
            $("#loading").show();
        }).ajaxStop(function(){
            $("#loading").hide();
        }).ajaxError(function(){
            alert("Error on load page!");
        });
        $(".tw-content ul li a").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var twLink = $(this).attr('href');
            console.log('Link: ' + twLink);
            $("#Container").load(twLink + ' #ContainerChild');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: "// not sure why does it need + "#ContainerChild" here?", well i want only the content of ContainerChild id load there.

Comment: I've changed the above script a bit, please check if it works?